# How to attach an object which is not persisted to an object loaded from DB using NHIbernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an entity which looks likes this:

```
public class Driver
{
    IVehicle Vehicle {get;set;}
}
```

and several different classes which implement IVehicle (Car, Bike, Train...)

How can I select which specific implementation of IVehicle my Driver holds, and remember this selection the next time I load the driver from the DB?

I'm using NHibernate 3.0 for persistence together with FluentNHibernate for mapping.

**EDIT**

Ok I figured it out finally. I needed to map the vehicle and to map each subclass in the following way:

```
public void VehicleMap : ClassMap<IVehicle>
{
    public VehicleMap()
    {
        Id(v => v.Id); // Needed to add a property which will be used as Id
         DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("TYPE");
    } 
}

public void CareMap : SubclassMap<Car>
{
    public CarMap()
    {
         DiscriminatorValue("CAR");
    }
}
```

Additionally, I needed to disable lazy loading of the Vehicle from the driver mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide how your inheritance mapping will work. See the documentation http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance

Once you do, you can map your Driver class to cascade the Vehicle dependency. After that point NHibernate will automatically load the proper item from the database.

**UPDATE**

You will need to persist the type name as a string. Then your Vehicle class can be an unmapped property that does something like:

```
public class Driver
{
    private string vehicleTypeName;
    private IVehicle vehicle;

    public IVehicle Vehicle
    {
        get
        {
            if (vehicle == null)
            {
                vehicle = typeof(IVehicle).Assembly
                                   .CreateInstance(vehicleTypeName);
            }
            return vehicle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the different vehicles are not saved in the DB. Maybe my example was a bad one, so i'll try to explain in another way: The different vehicles are not entities in my system, they are utility classes which all implement a certain method differently. I need to figure out a way to save, for each driver, which utitly class to use (I select the proper class on creation, and I want tham choice to be rememberd..

Comment: Thanks, though I have found a different way to do it (edited my question with the solution)